# C++ string manipulation withing an utf8 locale

Tags: c++, string, utf-8

I want to do some simple string manipulation on a utf8 text file.
It will mean taking substrings from a line and outputting them rearranged.

As my linux computer has a utf8 locale and I don't intend to run the 
program elsewhere setting the locale to utf8 seemed to be the way to go.
Adapting an example I got to the  test program bellow.
If you give it a Greek word it outputs the same but outputing the result of substr just produces garbage.
Is there another function I can use or is making use of an utf8 locale totally the wrong way to go?

```
    #include <string>
    #include <iostream>

    int main()
    {
        std::string newwd;
        setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
        std::cout << "Enter greek word ";
        std::string wordgr;
        std::getline(std::cin, wordgr);
        std::cout << "The word is " << wordgr << "." << std::endl;
        newwd=wordgr.substr(2,1) ;
        std::cout << "3rd letter is " << wordgr.substr(2,1) << " <" << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: UTF-8 is a variable-length encoding; a given character in UTF-8 can be between one and six bytes long.  This causes the substr() method, *which operates on bytes, not characters* to produce unexpected results.  Greek characters in UTF-8 are NOT one-byte characters.  If you input a 4-character greek string and then called `std::string.length()` on that word, you would get a result greater than 4 bytes (most likely 8 bytes).

Comment: @KenP You should post this as an answer. :)

Comment: A very simple solution is to switch to wstring and wiostream and wchar_t throughout.

Comment: `std::string` is a container of `char`s, not letters in some encoding.

Comment: In case of "very simple solution", could you provide correct reference code please?

Comment: @vershov Yes I could. It differs from the original program in exactly 6 characters, all of them `w`. It cannot handle combining characters correctly, but `utf8-cpp` won't either.

Comment: @n.m. Wouldn't the encoding be enough for just output? If all he doesn't care about how it shows up on other systems, all he needs to do is set up his terminal or encoding for UTF-8 and it'll show up fine. The problem is string manipulation.

Comment: @remyabel `The problem is string manipulation` — that's exactly the problem `wchar_t` solves.

Comment: @n.m. Just for completeness, it is worth mentioning that `wchar_t` solves the problem *on Linux* (and OS X, I assume). If he ever wants a portable solution that works on Windows and DS9k as well, `char32_t` is the character type to use. All assuming the goal is only to handle code points, of course, which is just one of the many reasonable interpretations of “character,” as you know.

Comment: @ChristopherCreutzig Well, it was specifically asked for something that works on a single specific Linux machine. C+11-specific handling of Unicode will be nice when it works everywhere, last time I checked there were still issues. If things other than code points are needed then it's a lot bigger can of worms. Let's start with Unicode code points and develop from there gradually.

Answer (score 2):

UTF-8 is a variable-length encoding; a given character in UTF-8 can be between one and six bytes long.  This causes the substr() method, *which operates on bytes, not characters* to produce unexpected results.  Greek characters in UTF-8 are NOT one-byte characters.  If you input a 4-character greek string and then called `std::string.length()` on that word, you would get a result greater than 4 bytes (most likely 8 bytes).

Answer (score 1):

This works as expected on my system [and on IDEOne](http://ideone.com/NCsCQM).

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::wstring newwd;
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    std::wcout << "Enter greek word ";
    std::wstring wordgr;
    std::getline(std::wcin, wordgr);
    std::wcout << "The word is " << wordgr << "." << std::endl;
    newwd=wordgr.substr(2,1) ;
    std::wcout << "3rd letter is " << wordgr.substr(2,1) << " <" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Nice simple example.  Thanks very much.

Comment: It works incorrectly and displays "3rd letter is **?** <" instead of "3rd letter is **Й** <"

Comment: @vershov Your default locale is probably not UTF-8. What is your input (hex dump)?

Comment: @vershov Also what is your OS and compiler?

Comment: echo $LC_ALL shows ru_RU.utf-8
Data is as follows:
d0 a4 d0 a3 d0 99

Comment: Pretty strange: it doesn't work at MacOS 10.9 g++ 4.8.2 but works at Gentoo g++ 4.6.3. Both have locale ru_RU.utf-8

Comment: Does your program handle it on the Mac? I'm not sure how gcc is set up on Mac these days, could it be that it doesn't use the system locale?

Comment: @vershov Indeed from what I hear it looks like locale support in libstdc++ on MacOS is broken.

Answer (score 0):

If you would use UTF-8 in your applications you need to consider appropriate library: [utf8-cpp](http://utfcpp.sourceforge.net/). std::string or std::wstring is not an option since UTF-8 chars could have variable length, check [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) for more info.

Here is sample code that prove this concept.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include "source/utf8.h" // path to the utf8-cpp library header

int main()
{
        setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
        std::cout << "Enter greek word ";
        std::string wordgr;
        std::getline(std::cin, wordgr);
        std::cout << "The word is " << wordgr << "." << std::endl;
        std::string::iterator end_it = utf8::find_invalid(wordgr.begin(), wordgr.end());
        if (end_it != wordgr.end()) {
                std::cout << "Invalid utf-8 encoding" << std::endl;
                return 0;
        }
        // utf-8 string length
        std::cout << "Length is " << utf8::distance(wordgr.begin(), end_it) << std::endl;

        // utf-8 string symbol traverse
        std::string::iterator curr_it = wordgr.begin();
        std::string::iterator next_it = curr_it;
        utf8::next(next_it, wordgr.end());
        while(curr_it != wordgr.end()) {
                std::cout << std::string(curr_it, next_it) << " - ";
                curr_it = next_it;
                if (next_it != wordgr.end()) {
                        utf8::next(next_it, wordgr.end());
                }
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Output is as following:

```
./a.out 
Enter greek word Вова
The word is Вова.
Length is 4
В - о - в - а -
```

Comment: @n.m.: How is it wrong? Even a wider `CharT` type can't change the fundamental fact that `std::basic_string` is _not_ a container of Unicode characters, and cannot be made to be one. You need an abstraction on top.

Comment: @LightnessRacesInOrbit For the implementation in question `std::wstring` *is* a container of Unicode codepoints. Codepoints are not quite characters, but utf8-cpp offers nothing but codepoints either.

Comment: @n.m.: Okay then the answer is wrong because utf8-cpp is not the solution :) Thanks

Comment: Handling Unicode *characters* is a formidable task, and is pretty much overkill 99% of the time. Codepoints will do just fine.

Comment: Thanks for this very clear example.  I tried out utf8.h when first suggested but until I saw this example I was floundering.